# Won't insert values to database || won't run

Tags: android, sqlite

I recently made some small changes and can't seem to see what the error is causing all of this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Main

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.List;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AndroidAss2SQL extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addContact(new Coms("Gold", "100.00", "0"));
      db.addContact(new Coms("Silver", "300.00", "3"));
      db.addContact(new Coms("Wheat", "500.00", "4"));
      db.addContact(new Coms("Sugar", "750.00", "0"));
      db.addContact(new Coms("Coffee", "433.00", "9"));


        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all coms..");
        List<Coms> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

        for (Coms cn : contacts) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber() + " ,Quantity: " + cn.getQuan();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }



        Coms rando = db.getContact(1);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(rando));

        Coms rando1 = db.getContact(2);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(rando1));


        Coms rando2 = db.getContact(3);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(rando2));

        Coms rando3 = db.getContact(4);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(rando3));

        Coms rando4 = db.getContact(5);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(rando4));



    }
}
```

Com Class

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

public class Coms {

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _price;
    String _quan;

    // Empty constructor
    public Coms(){

    }
    // constructor
    public Coms(int id, String name, String price){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._price = price;
    }

    // constructor
    public Coms(String name, String price){
        this._name = name;
        this._price = price;
    }
    // constructor
        public Coms(String name){
            this._name = name;
        }
        public Coms(String name, String price, String quan){
            this._name = name;
            this._price = price;
            this._quan = quan;
        }
        public Coms(int id, String name, String price, String quan){
            this._id = id;
            this._name = name;
            this._price = price;
            this._quan = quan;
        }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
           return this._price;
        }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._price;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._price = phone_number;
    }
    // getting name
        public String getQuan(){
            return this._quan;
        }

        // setting name
        public void setQuan(String name){
            this._quan = name;
        }
}
```

DB Handler - Most of my changes were made in here, trying to add Quantity (quan)

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "comstuff";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "coms";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_QUAN = "quantity";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_QUAN + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Coms contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PRICE, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_QUAN, contact.getQuan()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Coms getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_QUAN }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Coms contact = new Coms(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }
    Coms getName(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PRICE, KEY_QUAN }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Coms contact = new Coms(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Coms> getAllContacts() {
        List<Coms> contactList = new ArrayList<Coms>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Coms contact = new Coms();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                //when this is changed from 2 to 3 it causes an error
                contact.setQuan(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Coms contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PRICE, contact.getPhoneNumber());
        values.put(KEY_QUAN, contact.getQuan());


        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Coms contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you uninstall your app after making change to your database table?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by uninstall? I am running it in an emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database tables are created only in the first run. If the database was created, onCreate would not be called again. Thus if you add a new column to a table and insert record involving the new column you will get error.
Either clear data or uninstall your app and then install and run again.
In the emulator check the 'Wipe user data'.

Comment: Or he can make a upgrade of database or use raw `DML` statements as well.